# How to send result javascript to php mail?

Tags: javascript, php, email

(sorry for my bad english).

I want to send result js to mail, so my code is :

In my page index.php :

```
<form action="send.php" method="post" name="action" id="action">
    <p>
        <label>info1 :</label>
        <input type="text" name="info1" id="info1" value="">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>info2 :</label>
        <input type="text" name="info2" id="info2" value="">
    </p>

    <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="javascript:calculate()">Calcul javascript</button>

<p>info3 : <span id="info3"></span></p>
<p>info4 : <span id="info4"></span></p>
<p>info5 : <span id="info5"></span></p>
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="javascript:result()">Result</button>

<input type="text" name="Name">
<input type="text" name="Email">
<input type="text" name="phone">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
```

ok, so i want send the result id (info3,info4 and info4) to my file php to send mail.

How i can do that please?

Comment: i didnt understand what you want, but i think you want to pass some value from js to php to send mail...if yes then write ajax....

Comment: yes @AbhijitJagtap it's this ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="result">Send</button>
```

// instead of submit input use a button `<button type="button" class="btn" id="result">Send</button>`
// if you want input value then simply write `var q = $(#info1).val();`

```
 $(function() {
    $("body").on("click", "#result", function() {
        var q = $(#info1).val();
        var p = $(#info2).val();
        var t = $(#info3).text();
        var m = $(#info4).text();
        var v = $(#info5).text();
        var n = "info3=" + t + "&info4=" + m + "&info5=" + v + "&info1=" + q + "&info2=" + p;

         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/mail.php",
            data: n,
            success: function(t) {
         alert('Mail Sent');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: this solution doesn't works for me ... in DOM i can see "info1=okforthisinfo&info2=okforthisinfo&**info5=**&Name=myNamedf&Email=MyEmail&Phone=Myphonefdfd"

Comment: thks a lot @Sagar this solution is good i think because i can see in dom the post request, but i want tis informartion when i send the form in submit button.

Comment: When i click to send, nothing happens ...

Comment: you are the best, i just add an onclick="javascript:result()" on my button and that's work fine.... THKssss Bro.

Answer (score 0):

> Load data asynchronously from the server using GET or POST HTTP
>   requests. Set data type (xml, json, script, text, html) and decode
>   returned data.

Sending POST requests is quite similar ($.post() in jQuery). However, there are lots of options available - more than can be covered in one post. Here's a useful helper function to get you started:

```
function postAjax(url, data, success) {
    var params = typeof data == 'string' ? data : Object.keys(data).map(
            function(k){ return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k]) }
        ).join('&');

    var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xhr.open('POST', url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState>3 && xhr.status==200) { success(xhr.responseText); }
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(params);
    return xhr;
}
// example request with data object
    var info3 = document.getElementById('info3').innerHTML;
    var info4 = document.getElementById('info4').innerHTML;
    var info5 = document.getElementById('info5').innerHTML;

postAjax('http://foo.bar/', {'info3' : info3, 'info4' :info4,'info5':info5   }, function(data){ console.log(data); });
```

Comment: thks for your answer but is more complicated for me, i'm noob, the solution of Sagar Singh is good i think but i need to sent all form info in same time.

Comment: thks for your help !!!